# How to create 10 VF page for one Custom Object..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-button

Based on my requirement I have to create 10 VF page for one Custom Object.
I have 10 fields on the custom object each field should have one page at the end of my page I have to place Next button it should navigate to next page at page 11 I need to button to save all the previous 10 page values.how to achieve this in please share your answers

Comment: Didn't you already ask this here: [is it possible to create 10 Vf page for one Custom Object in salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166690/is-it-possible-to-create-10-vf-page-for-one-custom-object-in-salesforce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go, 10 pages where each of 10 fields has its own page and the 11th page has a save button:

My10FieldPage

```
<apex:page controller="My10FieldController" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputfield value="{!obj[fields[i]]}" rendered="{!i < fields.size}"/>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" value="Next" rendered="{!i < fields.size}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rendered="{!i = fields.size}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My10FieldController

```
public class My10FieldController{

    public list<String> fields {get; set;}
    public Integer i {get; set;}
    public CustomObject__c obj {get; set;}

    public My10FieldController(){
        i = 0;
        obj = new CustomObject__c();
        fields = new list<String>{
            'Field1__c',
            'Field2__c',
            'Field3__c',
            'Field4__c',
            'Field5__c',
            'Field6__c',
            'Field7__c',
            'Field8__c',
            'Field9__c',
            'Field10__c'
        };
    }

    public PageReference next(){
        i = i + 1;
        return new PageReference('/apex/My10FieldPage');
    }

    public PageReference save(){
        insert obj;
        return new PageReference('/' + obj.Id);
    }
}
```